# how to use secured port using ssh

Tags: ssh

We have a process that is using a working secured port using this scp command like so:

`/usr/bin/scp -P 1234 -i /path/key_rsa /home/path/filename.txt user@remotehost:/tmp`

I'm working on a schell script, that will use `ssh`, but not sure how to use that same port of `1234`.

I tried `/usr/bin/ssh -D 1234 remotehost '. ~/my_profile; mkdir /test'` and its asking for the user pw. I know the keys are already established since the scp works fine for that user.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to use the `-p` option; `-D` is for dynamic port forwarding, that is to say creating port forwardings on an existing connection.